# Solve 4th order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following 4th order ODE but Wolfram Mathematica can not solve this problem. Could you kindly help me with this problem:

$y'''' (x)+y'' (x)+y(x)+y^3 (x)=0.$

$y(0)=0, y(1)=0, y''(0)=0, y''(1)=0,$

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
sol = DSolve[{y''''[x]+y''[x]+y[x]+y[x]*y[x]*y[x]==0,
         y[0]==0,y''[0]==0, y[1]==0,y''[1]==0}, y[x], x]
```

I tried to solve this equation in python with Newton's method. But python gives me a trivial solution ($y≡0$).

I am pretty sure that a non-trivial solution exists, because when I am trying to solve without cubic term ($y^3$) Mathematica gives me a trivial solution, but we have an analytical solution. It is $\sin(\pi*x)$

Comment: Try $y=0$, maybe?

Comment: Yes. It is a trivial solution, but I want to find non-trivial

Comment: If I am trying to solve without cubic term, mathematical gives me y=0 solution.

Comment: If I am trying to solve without cubic terms, Mathematica gives me a y=0 solution. But an analytical solution exists. It is sin (pi*x). That's why I am pretty sure that an analytical solution also exists for ODE with the cubic term.

Comment: $\sin(\pi x)$ is NOT a solution.

Comment: it is a solution for ODE without cubic term y′′′′(x)+y′′(x)+y(x)+=0.

Comment: No, it isn't, check your calculations.

Comment: @user82523  no. I'm guessing you got the computer to say that $\sin \pi x $  solves your ODE  above. But it really doesn't. Please write down, for your  $y =\sin \pi x ,$   the values of $y''$  and $y''$

Comment: @jjagmath   I'd say the OP has not done any calculations,  rather  found some way to give it to the CAS  . And got nonsense.

Comment: Yes, you are right. it is not a solution.

Comment: Does it mean that for the first ODE we have an only a trivial solution?

Comment: How many initial conditions do you usually need to determine a unique solution of an ODE of order $n$?

Comment: n conditions need

Comment: This is a 4th degree equation, so I'd guess that the four initial conditions determine a unique solution in this case (there are some exceptions to this rule that I don't know how to recognize) and that would mean that $0$ is the only solution.

Comment: yes, 4 boundary conditions.

Comment: @jjagmath  there seems to be a little play in the direction of periodic solutions. I began with $y = 4 \sin^3 x = 3 \sin x - \sin 3x \; . \; $  I also made the boundary conditions happen on endpoints $0, 2 \pi .$  This nonzero function solve $y'''' + 10 y'' + y = 0$ I guess the idea is that periodic means you don't get the full strength of the four boundary conditions.

Comment: Does it mean that I can get only a trivial solution?

Comment: Duplicate of your first question, user82523: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4401001/solve-4th-order-ode

Answer (score 1):

If there is a non-trivial solution $u$, then $y=u/L$ solves
$$
y''''+y''+y+L^2y^3=0
$$
with the same homogeneous boundary conditions. As this adds a degree of freedom, one is free to chose an extra condition that forces the solution to be non-trivial, such as $y'(0)=1$ or $\int_0^1y^2\,dx=1$.

Using the BVP solver of scipy this can be implemented as

```
def ode(t,y,p) : return y[1],y[2],y[3],-y[2]-y[0]-p*y[0]**3
def bc(y0,y1,p): return y0[0], y0[1]-1, y0[2], y1[0], y1[2]

x = np.linspace(0,1,21)
y = [np.sin(np.pi*x)/np.pi, np.cos(np.pi*x),0*x,0*x]

res = solve_bvp(ode,bc,x,y,p=[100])

print(res.message,res.p[0])
```

The above code invariably results in $p=-1134$, which can obviously not be the square of a real parameter. That is only valid for a initial guess that is a single hill, modification of the initial guess to a higher frequency finds solutions with an even more negative value for $p$.

Now if the last term had a negative sign, $$y''''+y''+y-y^3=0,$$ this procedure would have produced a solution with $L=\sqrt{1134}$.